Access denied to .NET Standard 2.0 - Azure Function App
Everything on my laptop syncs to OneDrive, and I experience the following error message when trying to build my function app in Visual Studio.

The "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task failed unexpectedly. System.IOException: Access to the path "D:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Functions\FunctionName\obj\Debug\net8.0\WorkerExtensions\buildout\bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0" is denied.

It seems to happen in the file Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets. It looks like it is trying to remove it. I have tried running Visual Studio as administrator, clean and rebuild the solution, deleting the debug-folder, yet without any luck.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Seems the issue is in the OneDrive not related to VS, you need to give access to allow deleting files.

Even if I move it to a folder that is not synced with OneDrive, still error still persist.

Please share the csproj and host.json

Have you given full control for the user to the folder?


Access to the path "D:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\WorkerExtensions\buildout\bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0" is denied.

This clearly states that you are not have access to do it.

Even if I move it to a folder that is not synced with OneDrive, still error still persist.

To access a file , one needs to give control and I have followed Document.

Go to the folder, right click on it
Then click on Properties, then click on Security


Then select edit and give full user access to it as below:

Then you can access this file.
Try adding below to property group in csproj:
<OutputPath>C:\BuildOutput\Debug</OutputPath>

Or use a temporary folder which is not synced and check.
